# Node JS Rest Service using like operator inito MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to Node JS Develop. I have developed a specific REST service with Express and Mongo DB.
Now I need to develop a rest service that when I pass some letter get an array of items that have these letters. I suppose that I could develop a GET Rest service using like operator.
I have tried with this code but is wrong:

```
router.get('/tire/autocomplete/:size', VerifyToken, function(req,res){
var size=req.params.size;
TechInfo.find({ Size: new RegExp(size, 'i') }).toArray(err, techinfos) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Size tires available', tires :techinfos}});
});
});
```

and this my model Schema

```
var TechInfoSchema = new Schema({

"ID_code" :{type: Number, required: true},
"inches" : {type: Number, required: true},
"Brand" : {type: String, required: true},
"Size" : {type: String, required: true},
"type" : {type: String, required: true}
},{
collection: 'techInfo'
});

var TechInfo = db.model('TechInfo',TechInfoSchema)
module.exports = TechInfo;
```

When i call my rest service using postman i recieve this error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /api/v1.0/equipment/tires/autocoplete</pre>
</body>
```

There is some exaple that i can see about rest service to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

why are you converting the final result using find to an array ? it already is an array

```
router.get('/tire/autocomplete', VerifyToken, function(req,res){
var size=req.params.size;
TechInfo.find({ Size: new RegExp(size, 'i') },(err, techinfos) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
        console.log(err);
    }else{
    res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Size tires available', tires :techinfos}});
    }

});
});
```

I just gave this answer as a rough idea. If this does not solve it update the post with your schema as well (model)